# Send a "TCP message" when triggered from a webpage

Tags: tcp, http, html

I have a program running on my workstation that takes an input as follows

```
echo mycommand >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1234
```

I would like to be able to send the "mycommand" to the specified port on the localhost machine via a click on a webpage so non-savvy people can execute the command easily.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: This could be done rather trivially with a basic PHP script; otherwise you're going to have to read up on CGI scripting, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite complicated to do this properly, generating an html page with a form and using a proper `POST` request, perhaps even with authorisation by password. Provided you are on a local network and do not mind anyone connecting, you can get someway towards a demonstration of what could be done with a simple shell script using `socat` to manage the connection.

Create a shell script, say `/tmp/myscript` with contents

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

running command" |
sed 's/$/\r/'
if echo mycommand >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1234
then echo OK
else echo fail
fi
date
```

Don't forget to make it executable with `chmod +x /tmp/myscript`. Then run

```
socat tcp-listen:8001,reuseaddr,fork exec:/tmp/myscript
```

and you should be able to connect your browser to `http://yourhostname:8001/`
to trigger the command. Or for your testing use `curl -v http://localhost:8001/`
and you should see something like

```
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8001 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8001
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< 
running command
OK
Wed Aug 23 21:04:47 CEST 2017
```

This is less than perfect, as some browsers may cache the result and not actually connect, hence the date output as a check. By using port 8001 you do not need to run socat as root. If you want to use the usual server port 80 (so your url is just `http://yourhostname`) you need to do `sudo socat ...`.

If you are familiar with python, ruby, perl or many other languages, they all provide simple web servers that can handle POST requests correctly.